# Another Perpetual Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

Since the community appears to enjoy Riley riddles, I have another one for the community to solve. As always, good luck to you all!

> Witness the prefix, it looks similar to you; built with some wicker, and wire too.
>
> Knowing the infix, will help you a lot; like one or the other, or maybe not.
>
> Recognize the suffix, above you will see; the backbone required, to build your knees.
>
> Open your mind, this word an illusion; no, just to youth, with play in fusion.

Comment: is the acrostic your favorite radio station? :D

Comment: @SteveV Nope, my favorite radio station is 95.1 The Rocket; but I remember back home we had one similar to this! HAHA The acrostic is intentional. :)

Comment: Acrostic: anagram of **work**. then with the next letters it's **inept**

Comment: @YoutRied that's ironic :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution

> Is the word you are looking for **work**?

Witness the prefix, it looks similar to you; built with some wicker, and wire too.

> The prefix in this case is 'w'. It looks similar to u, and is present in wicker, wire and witness.

Knowing the infix, will help you a lot; like one or the other, or maybe not.

> The infix is 'or'. Or is used multiple in the hint.

Recognize the suffix, above you will see; the backbone required, to build your knees.

> The suffix is 'k' which is required to build the word knees.

Open your mind, this word an illusion; no, just to youth, with play in fusion.

> People often say that if you enjoy what you do you never work a day in your life making it an illusion to those who fuse it with play. Also the acrostic **WKRO** is an anagram for work.